# Ensure that the method under test has thrown the expected exception, NOT any other part of the test case set up

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework, expected-exception

I am using Visual Studio Unit Test Cases.
I have written the Unit test case where Argument Exception is expected from the method under test `MethodUnderTest`. Suppose if any other part of the test case (Setup part) throws the expected exception `ArgumentException`, Then I want to enforce that my test case should fail. It should pass only in case Setup is correct and `instance.MethodUnderTest();` line of code throws `ArgumentException`.

I can achieve using `try catch`, but I want to know is there any better approach to achieve this.

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void TestCaseMethod()
{        
    // Set up
    Mock<ITestClass> testM = new Mock<ITestClass>();
    AnimalClass instance = new AnimalClass(testM.Object);

    // call the method under test
    instance.MethodUnderTest();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know of any built in way, but you could wrap up the method in an assert exception

```
private void AssertException<T>(Action method)
    where T : Exception
{
    try
    {
        method();
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (T e)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Then call with

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCaseMethod()
{        
    // Set up
    Mock<ITestClass> testM = new Mock<ITestClass>();
    AnimalClass instance = new AnimalClass(testM.Object);

    // call the method under test
    AssertException<ArgumentException>(instance.MethodUnderTest)
}
```

Or, if your method takes in parameters or returns values

```
AssertException<MyException>(() => instance.ParameterisedFunction(a, b));
```

Comment: Assert.Throws should take care of this as the below answer

Comment: That's NUnit, the question specified VS Test framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a more advanced unit testing framework, like NUnit. you can do things like:

```
// Act
var result = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => instance.MethodUnderTest));

// Assert
Assert.IsInstanceOf<ArgumentException>(result);
```